# Why does the `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT` constant drop the decimal place character?

Tags: php

```
$quantity = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'quantity', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
```

Input: `100.25`

Output: `10025`

How can I preserve the `.` character?

Comment: The was already answered. The documentation is [Types of filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php). Unfortunately it is not very intuitive. Both the Sanitize filter needs to be used and a *supplementary* Filter flag (which is missing in the post) must be supplied in this situation.

Comment: (Also, the posted code doesn't multiply by 100: it removes the "offending" decimal, try "100.1234" as input :-)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try this...

```
$quantity = filter_input(
              INPUT_GET, 
              'quantity', 
              FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, 
              FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION
            );
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/2pItppel).

Comment: I don't understand the point of this filter without the `FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION` - Surely the very definition of a "float" is that it has a "floating" point i.e decimal?

Comment: @Andy I think the reason is... PHP. :D

Comment: I think you're right, I've scratched my head a few times about other PHP weirdness since I wrote that comment P.S: Your website font reminds me of old school point and click games :)

Comment: @Andy I was obsessed with emulators at the time. :D

Answer (score 23):

Reading the documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php shows that `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT` has the following effect:

> Remove all characters except digits, +- and optionally .,eE.

Turning this rather poorly formed sentence around:

> This removes all characters from the input except digits (0-9). With optional flags, it is possible to also allow the characters . (dot) , (comma) e (exponent) and E (exponent)

So, your code example isn't multiplying, but it is stripping the decimal point.

**Solution**:

You need to set the option `FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION` in your function call to allow the decimal point:

```
$quantity = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'quantity', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
```

Answer (score 8):

You want:

```
$quantity = filter_var(100.25, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);

print_r($quantity);
```

http://codepad.org/ch66qJru

Woops.. You'll want to still use `filter_input` as you currently have as well as the same first two args. I ended up using `filter_var` so I could test it in codepad and forgot to change it back :P

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use `FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT`, with a quick feedback note if it doesn't match:

```
    $quantity = (filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'quantity', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT))
                ?filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'quantity', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT):
                "Invalid Decimal Number";

    print_r($quantity);
```