# mysql decimal and double data issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to store currency data in mysql. Here I used `decimal` and `double` datatype for it.

This is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions (
  tb_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tb_our_rate DECIMAL(15, 2) NOT NULL,
  tb_bank_rate DECIMAL(15, 2) NOT NULL,
  tb_lkr_funds DOUBLE(15, 2) NOT NULL,
  tb_aud_funds DOUBLE(15, 2) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (tb_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I tried inserting some values to this columns. This is my inserted values.

```
133.11
120.20
-12312,123,123.02
-12312,231,423.32
```

This is how it insert to database:

```
mysql> select * from transactions\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
   tb_our_rate: 13311.00
  tb_bank_rate: 12020.00
  tb_lkr_funds: -1231212312302.00
  tb_aud_funds: -1231223142332.00
    date_added: 2015-11-26 07:36:01
*************************** 2. row ***************************
```

UPDATE: 
This is how my insert query work:

```
$our_rate   = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'our_rate', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
$bank_rate  = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'bank_rate', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
$lkr_funds  = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lkr_funds', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
$aud_funds  = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'aud_funds', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);

$query = "INSERT INTO transaction_banks( 
                              tb_our_rate
                            , tb_bank_rate
                            , tb_lkr_funds
                            , tb_aud_funds
                            , date_added
                            ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

if ($insert_stmt){
    $insert_stmt->bind_param('dddd', 
                                $our_rate
                              , $bank_rate
                              , $lkr_funds
                              , $aud_funds
                            );
  $insert_stmt->execute(); 
}
```

Can anybody tell me what is the problem of this?

Comment: lose the commas for one thing

Comment: Yes and decimal values also inserting incorrectly

Comment: show a create table statement and the actual insert statements. Dont describe them

Comment: update question with table stucture

Comment: Drew meant to lose the commas before inserting them into your table. Format your number properly before inserting.

Comment: @Drew, I update the question with my insert query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks good to me. Don't do inserts with commas in the numbers. I am afraid to even try.

```
create table thing99
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    tb_our_rate DECIMAL(15, 2) NOT NULL,
    tb_bank_rate DECIMAL(15, 2) NOT NULL,
    tb_lkr_funds DOUBLE(15, 2) NOT NULL,
    tb_aud_funds DOUBLE(15, 2) NOT NULL
);


insert thing99(tb_our_rate,tb_bank_rate,tb_lkr_funds,tb_aud_funds) values
(133.11,120.20,-12312123123.02,-12312231423.32);

select * from thing99;
+----+-------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| id | tb_our_rate | tb_bank_rate | tb_lkr_funds    | tb_aud_funds    |
+----+-------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  1 |      133.11 |       120.20 | -12312123123.02 | -12312231423.32 |
+----+-------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

### Edit:

Just found it. You have to use option 2 below.

```
$our_rate   = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'our_rate', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);

$our_rate2=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'our_rate',
FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);



echo $our_rate."<br>";
echo $our_rate2."<br>";
```

**tested**

From the Manual page on [Filter Flags](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php) and FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION:

[image]

Comment: Drew, Do I need to remove commas before inserting into mysql? Because my post array coming date like this `aud_funds 
-12312,231,423.32`

Comment: filter takes out the commas. It leaves digits and +/- and the period

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT`. This removes the `.` in your input.

Check this [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php).

It sanitizes the input, and only allows `+` and `-`.

You can use `FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION`:

```
$our_rate   = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'our_rate', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
$bank_rate  = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'bank_rate', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
$lkr_funds  = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lkr_funds', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
$aud_funds  = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'aud_funds', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066809/why-does-the-filter-validate-number-float-constant-drop-the-decimal-place-char) previous question about this problem.